# javascript global/ local variable

Tags: javascript

```
function myFunction() {
    console.log(a);
    console.log(foo());
    var a = 1;
    foo() {
        return 2;
    }
}

myFunction();
```

can someone explain me the output of the above function. When I tried there was no output thrown. If that is correct, then why does it happen that way?

Comment: Why are you logging before you initialize? Also, you need to define `foo()` as a function as well. IE `var foo = function() { return 2; }` then use `console.log(foo);`

Comment: Check your console, there should be an error.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, you should declare variables before using them.

```
function myFunction() {
    var a = 1;
    var foo = function foo() {
        return 2;
    }
    console.log(a);
    console.log(foo());
}

myFunction();
```